# How to set a query for two different tables with Django Q?

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Categories(models.Model):
  category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
.
.
class Post(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
  ...
```

There a lot more lines, but are irrelevant.

views.py

```
def view_homepage(request, slug=None):
categories_list = Categories.objects.all().order_by("id")
today = timezone.now().date()

posts_list = Post.objects.active()
if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
    posts_list = Post.objects.all()

users = User.objects.all()

query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    posts_list = posts_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query)|
            Q(subtitle__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query) &
            Q(username__icontains=query)
            ) & users.filter(Q(author__icontains=query))
paginator = Paginator(posts_list, 5) # Show 25 contacts per page
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    'queryset': queryset,
    'posts': queryset,
    'categories': categories_list,  
}
return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

The problem I have is within the if query: statement, I need the posts_list variable to be able to hold information from multiple table, in this particular case it works with title, subtitle, content because they belong within the same table, the Post table. But, username is in another and is linked with a foreign key also categories.

Question: How do I make it so a person can search information from multiple tables using the search bar.
**Again, it works with, title, subtitle and content, this is certain. 
Thanks in advance.

***I need username and category, the views.py sample doesn't work.

Comment: `Queryset` is meant to work for only one model, you cannot concatenate two querysets from different models to one queryset.

Comment: Is there a solution to this then? Anything?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear; are you after a query on two different tables, or do you want something that can query a single table across a relationship? You do the latter with the double-underscore syntax.

Comment: You can do `list(queryset1) + list(queryset2)` to create a list, but after that you cannot process it any further with paginator and stuff.

Comment: I guess I won't put such a thing then anyway. Thank you though.